# Young adult short story about barbaric duels on the surface of a moon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult

I recently had a recollection of a short story that I was assigned to read while in an American middle school in the early '80s.  Details are scarce sadly but I believe it may have come from a sci-fi anthology geared toward teenagers because I recall having a choice from a number of different stories.  Here's what else I remember:

- It involved barbaric duels between beings, gladiator style, that took place on the cratered surface of a desolate moon.  My recollection is that it was Earth's moon but I'm not sure.
- As a short story it was about a particular duel between what I believe was the human protagonist and an alien opponent and the races were adversaries.
- I recall a morality element where the human protagonist wrestled with the idea of killing his opponent in the end.

Comment: The second point requires an obligatory mention of Frederic Brown's "[Arena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arena_(short_story))" even though it really doesn't match the first point.

Comment: @DavidW I read the summary of Arena and I agree it seems very similar with the exception of setting. My recollection is the story I'm talking about took place on the cratered surface of a/the moon. But it may have been yet another derivative of Arena. If that is the case then it would put the publication between 1944 and ~1982.